# Spring JPA: Join and OrderBy in Specification

Tags: spring, hibernate, join, specifications, criteria-api

I have some problem with Specification construction.
I have two entities:
**Candidate:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidates")
public class Candidate extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long categoryId;

    …
}
```

and **Category**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "categories-candidates")
    private List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
    …
}
```

Some `Candidate` has null in `category` field. And I need to sort by Category's `name` field, not by some Candidate's fields. At the same time, I have where-condition by Candidate's field `uploadId`.
I need to create Specification to equivalense of SQL (I checked this request - this is exactly what I need):

```
SELECT * FROM candidates 
LEFT JOIN categories ON candidates.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE candidates.upload_id = 1 
ORDER BY categories."name"
```

I tried to do that:

```
public static Specification<Candidate> candidatesByUploadId(final long uploadId) {
    return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<Candidate, Category> join = root.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(join.get("name")));
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("uploadId"), uploadId);
    });
}
```

But I can't:

- There is no "uploadId" field in join, 'cause this is join left join for Category-to-Candidate, not vica versa
- I need all Candidate records, even with null Category, so I can't use inner join
- I can't use `JoinType.RIGHT` - it doesn't supported and I got the Exception
- I tryed to change relation owner in entities, but it didn't help me
- I shouldn't use `@Query` things, I need to do it into `Specification<>`
- If I write `return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("uploadId"), uploadId);` with `root` instead `join`, I haven't join results

How I can get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing is first**

You need to specify one column as `updatable = false` & `insertable = false`, as you are specifying two properties in `Candidate` entity (`category` & `categoryId`). So your `Candidate` entity will look like following

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidates")
public class Candidate extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "category_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long categoryId;

    …
}
```

Then your specification will look like following:

```java
public class CandidateSpecification {

    // Specification for upload id clause
    public static Specification<Candidate> candidatesByUploadId(final long uploadId) {
        if(uploadId == null) return null;
        return ((root, query, builder) -> {
            return builder.equal(root.get(Candidate_.uploadId), uploadId);
        });
    }
    
    // Specification for left join category.
    public static Specification<Candidate> joinCategory() {
    
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            root.join(Candidate_.category, JoinType.LEFT);
            return builder.conjuction();
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

Now the query part

```
public List<Candidate> getCandidatesByUploadIdSortedByCategoryName(Long uploadId) {
    Specification<Candidate> specification = Specification.where(CandidateSpecification.candidatesByUploadId(uploadId))
    .and(CandidateSpecification.joinCategory);

    return candidateRepository.findAll(specification, Sort.by("category.name"));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. By the way, I uses `findAll(specification, pageble)` method, so I need to add sorting into custom Pageble object. So now I decided the problem =)
But I have a couple of questions, if I may: 
- Why I need to add `updatable = false, insertable = false` to `categoryId` too? I works without it. 
- If I have two scecifications, SQL-request contains strainge extra where-condition `and 1=1` so I had to combine two specifications to one. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: you have two property category and category_id pointing the category_id, i assume the long type category_id is just for reading purpose to reduce the join operation during querying. While writing Candidate jpa will be confused and cannot decide, which properties value to consider as foreign key for category. So to clear the confusion, long category_id is marked as updatable and insertable false.

Comment: The whole purpose of specification is to generate reusable portions. Consider situation when you want uploadId clause in your query without fetching the category or fetch category based on some different condition, then you cannot reuse your specification. the 1=1 is coming from builder.conjuction from the category fetch specification. Each spec is supossed to return a predicate, but fetch category fetch does not contribute anything to the predicate/where clause, that is why truthy predicate builder.conjunction is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Join.getOn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html#getOn--) that transforms `Join` to `Predicate`.

```java
public static Specification<Candidate> candidatesByUploadId(final long uploadId) {
    return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<Candidate, Category> join = root.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(join.get("name")));
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("uploadId"), uploadId)
                              // here it is
                              .and(join.getOn());
    });
}
```

Comment: But this is not that join I need to :-(

Comment: Why? Have you tested it? The result should be exactly the same you need

Comment: As I wrote in 1st point, in this case I have left join for Category-to-Candidate, but I need left join for Candidate-to-Category. I saw it during debugging

Comment: Can you turn on SQL logging and put the result query? The easiest way is to add property `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Comment: 1. If I try to do this:
Join<Candidate, Category> join = root.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(join.get("name")));
return cb.and(     
  join.getOn(), 
  cb.equal(root.get("uploadId"), uploadId));
I get "Exception: null"

Comment: 2. If I try to do this:
Join<Candidate, Category> join = root.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(join.get("name")));
return cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("uploadId"), uploadId));
I get this:
    select
        can0_.id as id1_6_,
        ...
        can0_.category_id as categor12_6_,
        can0_.upload_id as upload_14_6_ 
    from
        _candidates can0_ 
    left outer join
        _categories cat1_ 
            on can0_.category_id=cat1_.id 
    where
        can0_.upload_id=1 
        and can0_.deleted=? 
    order by
        can0_.id desc limit ?

Comment: So, JOIN is that I need, actually
But how to add order by Category.name?

Comment: Predicate that is returned is used in query's `WHERE` clause. Then `join on` clause included in the query automatically from the relation ship of the entities.

Comment: @pr_unikitty can you provide the full log of `Exception: null` case?

Comment: @semyon-kirekov thank you for your advices. I can't provide fill log of `Exception: null`, 'cause I decided the problem. So, if I want to provide theese logs, I need to backtrack to a condition with problem. By the way, I uses some different way to add order to request =)